# MySQL locking processing large LOAD DATA INFILE when live SELECT queries still needed

Tags: mysql, locking, load-data-infile

Looking for some help and advice please from Super Guru MySQL/PHP pros who can spare a moment of their time.

I have a web application in PHP/MySQL which has grown over the years and gets alot of searches on it. Its hitting bottlenecks now when the various daily data dumps of new rows get processed using MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE.

Its a large MyISAM table with about 1.5 million rows and all the SELECT queries occur on it. When these take place during the LOAD DATA INFILE of about 600k rows (and deletion of out dated data) they just get backed up and take about 30+ minutes to be freed up making any of those searches fruitless.

I need to come up with a way to get that table updated while retaining the ability to provide SELECT results in a reasonable timeframe.

Im completely out of ideas and have not been able to come up with a solution myself as its the first time ive encountered this sort of issue.

Any helpful advice, solutions or pointers from similar past experiences would be greatly appreciated as I would love to learn to resolve this sort of problem.

Many thanks everyone for your time! J

Comment: Wouldn't switching to InnoDB solve this problem? It does not require table locks the way MyISAM does.

Comment: The reason im using MyISAM is for the live searches on this table to be quicker. Isn't MyISAM quicker for SELECTs than InnoDB or have I got that wrong? Is it safe to mix and match tables with InnoDB and MyISAM under one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyISAM doesn't support row-level locking, so operations like mysqldump are forced to lock the entire table to guarantee a consistent dump. Your only practical options are to switch to another table like (like InnoDB) that supports row-level locking, and/or split your dump up into smaller pieces. The small dumps will still lock the table while they're dumping/reloading, but the lock periods would be shorter.

A hairier option would be to have "live" and "backup" tables. Do the dump/load operations on the backup table. When they're copmlete, swap it out for the live table (rename tables, or have your code dynamically change which table they're using).. If you can live with a short window of potential stale data, this could be a better option.

Comment: My email stopped working but I kind of went along these lines without having seen the answer. I just started messing around and thought outside the box broke it down. Ive split it to 2 tables. One live and one process which now performs the updates on. Then renames the old table to delete and renames a temp version of the process table to live again and drops the renamed delete table. Seems to only take seconds renaming with the main time being the creation of the temp table copy of the process table. Appears to be working like a charm so far.

Comment: Thanks for your help Marc B much appreciated. Im pleased that what ive done seems to be thinking around the right lines :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CONCURRENT keywords for LOAD DATA INFILE. This way, when you load the data, the table is still able to server SELECTs.

Concerning the delete, this is more complicated. I would personally add a column called 'status' INT(1), who will define if the line is active or not( = deleted), and then partition my table with a rule based on this column status.

This way, it will be easier to delete all rows where status=0 :P I haven;t tested this last solution, I may do that in a near future.

The CONCURRENT keywords will work if your table is optimized. If there is any FREE_SPACE, then the LOAD DATA INFILE will lock the table.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch your table storage engine from MyISAM to InnoDB. InnoDB provides row-locking (as opposed to MyISAM's table-locking) meaning while one query is busy updating or inserting a row, another query can update a different row at the same time.